# Removing glibc dependency when compiling with gcc

Tags: gcc, glibc

Is it possible to compile a program using gcc without depending on glibc?

```
void main(){}
```

> ./libtest: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not
> found (required by ./libtest)

EDIT: It seems I had to compile with -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to compile a program using gcc without depending on glibc?

Yes, there are alternative `libc` versions, such as Musl, uClibc, dietLibc, etc. See their documentation on how to use them.

Your problem *does not appear* to be a GLIBC dependency, but rather a mismatch between your build and your target hosts. In particular, your target has older GLIBC than your build host.

The easiest to solution for *that* problem is to build on an old-enough system -- your binary will run on anything that is as-old or newer. You could do that inside a VM or in a docker container, so you don't have to downgrade your main system.

You could also link your program statically (add `-static` flag), but beware -- for many non-trivial programs this will make your binary *less* portable.

Comment: "You could also link your program statically (add -static flag)" -when and where is this flag added?